# Recovering a lost git repository

Tags: git

I accidently did an 'rm -rf foldername' on my git bash. So I lost my entire git repository. These had several local commits that were not pushed to the remote. I noticed that I can recover the .git folder with a data recovery tool. If I clone the repo from remote(which does not have my local commits) and overwrite the .git with the .git i recovered, will I get back my local commits?

Comment: If you have really recovered the whole `.git` folder, there's no reason to clone anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the .git directory itself you can clone directly from that.  Put the .git directory into a subdirectory and then clone that subrepository:

```
mkdir temporary
mv .git-recovered temporary/.git
git clone temporary fixed-repository
```

Everything that is committed in git is stored in that single directory, so as long as you've got that (with nothing missing), you should be able to easily recover all your commits just fine.

EDIT:

You can actually simplify the process as suggested by @chepner.

```
mkdir fixed
mv .git-recovered fixed/.git
cd fixed
git reset --hard # restores the working directory files
```

Comment: You don't even have to clone; `git clone` essentially copies `.git` from a remote repository. If you already have the `.git` directory, you simply need to check out a branch.